# Semaphore execution

Tags: semaphore, race-condition, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

P1 and P2 are two concurrent processes interacting over shared data as shown below.Tell me whether the property of mutual exclusion is satisfied for the given codes or if not,provide a corrected version that satisfies the mutual exclusion property.

```
do {
signal(mutex);
// critical section
wait(mutex);
// remainder section
} while (TRUE);
```

Code for P2:

```
do {
wait(mutex);
// critical section
signal(mutex);
// remainder section
} while (TRUE);
```

Note:
The definition of wait() is as follows:

```
wait(S) {
while S <= 0
; // no-op
S-- ;
}
```

The definition of signal() is as follows:

```
signal(S) {
S++;
}
```

Comment: Is this part of some assignment ?

Comment: Sure sounds like it.

Comment: yes it is a part of a assignment

Comment: No answers for this?